# Sinch SDK uses intranet or internet? I want to build an video calling application b/w raspberry pi and android through intranet

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, intranet

Actually there is only a router in the medium which connects raspberry pi and android and no internet b/w them to place a video call.

Answer (score 0):

I think they use INTERNET. I used one time and the connection was made by th UserID that the user get when log in on the app.

You can check the documentation here https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/android/

Maybe you can create a connection setting a fixed IP.

Comment: please provide me some links for local video broadcast from pi camera and receive them in android like a video call alert.